# How to execute mvn with multiline script?

Tags: shell, maven

I'm writing test cases using JMeter in a maven project. I'd like to provide shell and batch script examples for every test case, so others can try these tests out easily. On the other hand, these scripts are examples about how to one can configure test cases via parameters. The importance of being multiline formatted os being able understand easily the script parameteres, especially when I'll have scripts with 10+ parameters.

An mvn command executing the script in batch format looks like below. The batch format works like charm.

```
mvn clean verify -DjMeterScript=JMXFileName.jmx ^
  -Djmeter.url=test.environment.url ^
  -Djmeter.port=6080 ^
  -Djmeter.protocol=http ^
  -Djmeter.debugMode=1 ^
  -Djmeter.viaFiddler=1 ^
```

However, the shell format doesn't work. According to internet ultimate knowledge a multiline shell scripts should be formatted like below.

```
mvn clean verify -DjMeterScript=JMXFileName.jmx \
  -Djmeter.url=test.environment.url \
  -Djmeter.port=6080 \
  -Djmeter.protocol=http \
  -Djmeter.debugMode=1 \
  -Djmeter.viaFiddler=1 \
```

When I execute the script with `./shellScriptName.sh` where the script contains the example above, I'm getting the error below.

The question is how to format a shell script properly which calls maven?

**Update - it happens only on Windows 10 - WSL with Hyper**:

- Git bash on Windows 10 works fine
- Macbook Pro also works fine
- with any linux it works fine

**Error message**:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "
[ERROR] ". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: I've never seen this. What shell are you using to execute your script (`dash`, `bash`, ..., check the shebang if any and what it refers to)? Does the file have a specific encoding? Could you reproduce your problem with a simpler script (for example just write a script with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env sh` and simply `mvn clean` as content).

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any space after jmx.

```html
mvn clean verify -DjMeterScript=JMXFileName.jmx\
  -Djmeter.url=test.environment.url \
  -Djmeter.port=6080 \
  -Djmeter.protocol=http \
  -Djmeter.debugMode=1 \
  -Djmeter.viaFiddler=1 \
```

This will also works

```html
mvn spring-boot:run\
    -DDB_HOST=${DB_HOST} \
    -DDB_PORT=${DB_PORT} \
    -DDB_NAME=${DB_NAME} \
    -DDB_USER=${DB_USER} \
    -DDB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD} \
```

Comment: Space or no space, it should work in *sh shells.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and you should use ^ symbol to break lines but also contain all arguments with dot in quotation marks. I think you don't have to add ^ symbol in last line.

So in your case it should look like this:

```
mvn clean verify -DjMeterScript="JMXFileName.jmx" ^
  -D"jmeter.url"="test.environment.url ^
  -D"jmeter.port"=6080 ^
  -D"jmeter.protocol"=http ^
  -D"jmeter.debugMode"=1 ^
  -D"jmeter.viaFiddler"=1
```